# s3 representation in 2d in matrix form

Tags: representation-theory

Trying to arrive at how matrix form of standard representation of Symmetric Group S3 has the form $((-1,1),(0,1))$ for permutation $(1,2)$. Please let me know details. - Thanks

Comment: While the representation is called "standard", what's "standard" is only the representation by automorphisms on the orthogonal complement of $(1,1,1)$ in $\mathbb R^3$. This doesn't correspond to a "standard" matrix representation because there's no canonical basis of that space. Thus, you have to arbitrarily choose a basis to get a matrix representation from this representation. In other words, it doesn't make sense to say that "a matrix of the standard representation has the form ...".

Comment: @joriki True. I was looking at http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Standard_representation_of_symmetric_group:S3 and trying to derive (12) 2d rep using (e1-e2) and (e2-e3) as basis.

Comment: @joriki Agreed. I was trying to use (e1-e2) and (e2-e3) as basis

Answer (score 2):

Apply the permutation to the basis vectors and express the result in terms of the basis vectors. I'll do it for $e_2-e_3$: applying $(12)$ yields $e_1-e_3$. This is $1\cdot(e_1-e_2)+1\cdot(e_2-e_3)$, so the two entries that describe the contribution from $e_2-e_3$ to $e_1-e_2$ and from $e_2-e_3$ to $e_2-e_3$ are both $1$. You can get the other two entries analogously by applying the permutation to the other basis vector.

Comment: Great. I understood perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it is bit more work to get the 2D rep from 3D permutation representation.

Using $(e1-e2,e2-e3)$, one can build an intertwaining operator - say $S$ which in our case is $((1,0),(-1,1),(0,-1))$.

Consider $P$ as an element of Permutation matrix and $D$ as 2D matrix. From the equation, $S D = P S$,
we have $D=S^{-1}PS$.

I wrote the following SAGE/numpy code to generate these matrices.

```
import numpy as np
a1=matrix([[1,0],[-1,1],[0,-1]])
print "Intertwining op as e1-e2,e2-e3"
show(a1)
a1I=np.linalg.pinv(np.matrix(a1))
print "psuedo inverse of intertwaining operator-rewritten in rational form"
b1=matrix([[2/3,-1/3,-1/3],[1/3,1/3,-2/3]])
for el in SymmetricGroup(3):
    print "Permuation ",el
    print "Corresponding 2D matrix"
    show(b1*el.matrix()*a1)
```